# typing in richtextbox need to fire an event on keypress

Tags: .net

i have a richtextbox in asp.net i need an alert on key press please help me regarding this

thanks in advance

Devi

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `richTextBox` use `TextArea`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
     function onKeyDownMyTextArea() {
          //Do stuff
          alert("you have pressed key.");
     }
  -->
</script>

<body>
  <textarea name="MyTextArea" cols="28" rows="4" onkeydown="onKeyDownMyTextArea();">/textarea>
</body>
```